# Button listener doesn't work

Tags: android, button

I have two buttons one of them click listener works perfect and the other doesn't work I tried to delete code and rewrite it, clean, rebuild and nothing solve the problem.
the Button doesn't work is pauseButton, the others work perfectly.
if any one has an idea please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
        if (orderEndTrip != null && !orderEndTrip.equals("")) {

                        accept_order.setText("تم التوصيل ");
                        accept_order.setOnClickListener(new

                           View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                amountdialog();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        accept_order.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        EndTrip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        EndTrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                EndTripFun();
                            }
                        });
                        pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        pauseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {


                                Log.e("pause click", "true");
                                if (t == 1) {
                                    pauseBtn.setText("توقف");
                                    Log.e("stop ", "true");
                                    starttime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                                    handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 0);
                                    pauseFun();
                                    t = 0;
                                } else {
                                    pauseBtn.setText("استمرار");
                                    Log.e("resume", "true");
                                    time.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                    timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                                    handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimer);
                                    resumeTracking();
                                    t = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        });




                    }
```

Comment: which button is not working??

Comment: Is button id given correctly?, if yes display a toast inside the buttton on click and see if toast shows up

Comment: Add your logcat.This will be help to understand your error

Comment: also post your layout xml please

Comment: sorry, but i'm not going to guess which button does not work.

Comment: Check both buttons id in xml file and match where you initialised these buttons in your java code. sometimes while copy paste we mismatch id.

Comment: i edit the question ..

Comment: i checked the id and it is correct ..i also change the id and still the same problem

Comment: is pause button not working?

Comment: yes the only one who doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something as below..

### In your layout

```
<Button android:id="@+id/accept_order"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="تم التوصيل "
android:onClick="onAcceptOrderClicked" />

<Button android:id="@+id/endTrip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="End Trip"
android:onClick="onEditTripClicked" />

<Button android:id="@+id/pauseorder"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="توقف"
android:onClick="onPauseOrderClicked" />
```

### In your activity

On loading event onCreate()  use your if logic..

```
Button acceptOrderBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept_order);
Button endTripBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endTrip);
Button pauseOrderBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseorder);

if (orderEndTrip != null && !orderEndTrip.equals("")) {
 acceptOrderBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }else{
 endTripBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 pauseOrderBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
}
```

---

```
public void onAcceptOrderClicked(View v) {
// do your accept order logic here
// amountdialog();
}

public void onEditTripClicked(View v) {
// does something interesting
}

public void onPauseOrderClicked(View v) {
// does something interesting
}
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks you save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoint at try to debug your app using the debugger.To know how to use a debugger find in the link below : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html